# Using XDocument.Load(xmlreader) method?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I heard normally when using `XDocument`'s `Load` or `Parse` method the entire file loaded into memory that is why parsing large files with this method is not recommended...but what if I use the following overload to read a xml file

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(@"C:\OP\file.xml", settings),LoadOptions.None);
```

Does it still load the entire file into memory, if so, what is this overload good for?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that still loads the whole file's content into an in-memory representation. It's less useful than the `XElement.Load(XmlReader)` method which can be *really* useful to load just *part* of a document into memory at one time.

I'd view the `XDocument.Load(XmlReader)` method as mostly present for consistency - but I could see it being useful in cases where other APIs provide an `XmlReader` rather than the raw data. For example, you *could* have some data structure which provides "fake" XML access by allowing you to create an `XmlReader` from it. That way it would never need to serialize to the real XML which would then need parsing again.

Another use case would be where you want to use some aspects of `XmlReadSettings` which aren't avaliable in `LoadOptions`, such as ignoring comments or using a specific name table.

But no, you shouldn't use `XDocument.Load(XmlReader)` if you're concerned that the document doesn't fit into memory.

Comment: how much memory does a xml file of size say 20 MB take in memory and does that number change for different CPU'S (i.e. with different clock speeds and core's)

Comment: @Bumba: CPU won't change the amount of memory required at all. What *would* affect it would be the document structure (lots of elements/attributes with small amounts of data in them, or a few elements/attributes with huge amounts of data in them) - I would suggest you run tests with your actual data.

Comment: Isn't ability to configure `XmlReadSettings` useful in this case?

Comment: @Evk: You mean if you want to control ignoring comments, which can't be controlled via LoadOptions? Yes, I guess so. Will edit.